# Scroll to selected row when the row is selected programatic

Tags: scroll, kendo-grid, selecteditem

```
grid.kendoGrid({
    dataTextField: "Description",
    dataValueField: "ID",
    dataSource: {
        data: gridData
    },
    filterable: {
        extra: false,
        operators: {
            string: {
                startswith: $("#" + getId(controlPrefix, "hiddenFilterStartsWith")).val(),
                endswith: $("#" + getId(controlPrefix, "hiddenFilterEndsWith")).val(),
                eq: $("#" + getId(controlPrefix, "hiddenFilterEq")).val(),
                neq: $("#" + getId(controlPrefix, "hiddenFilterNeq")).val(),
                contains: $("#" + getId(controlPrefix, "hiddenFilterContains")).val()
            }
        },
        messages: {
            clear: $("#" + getId(controlPrefix, "hiddenFilterClear")).val(),
            filter: $("#" + getId(controlPrefix, "hiddenFilterFilter")).val(),
            info: $("#" + getId(controlPrefix, "hiddenFilterInfo")).val()
        }
    },
    columns: [
        { field: "ID", title: gridTitles[0], width: 200 },
        { field: "Description", title: gridTitles[1], width: 200 }
    ],
    height: 450,
    selectable: "row",
    change: function (e) {
        this.element.find(".k-grid-content").animate({
            scrollTop: this.select().offset().top - this.element.find('.k-grid-content').offset().top
        });
    }
});
```

> I have this kendo grid and I wanto to select a item and automatic scroll to it, the change event is triggered but when I select from code the offset().top has the same values for both elements and when I select it with the mouse it works
>
> Here I make the selection in the code

```
var employeeFilter = $("#" + getId(controlPrefix, inputControlId)).val();

if (employeeFilter != "") {
    grid.data("kendoGrid").select(grid.data("kendoGrid").tbody.find(">tr:has(td:contains('" + employeeFilter + "'))"));
}
```

> If somebody can help me to select the item using code and automatic scroll to it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your selector for the row is correct, but I shortened it like this:

```
grid.data("kendoGrid").select(grid.find("tr:has(td:contains('" + employeeFilter + "'))"));
```

The problem is how you compute the value for `scrollTop`. Since you use `animate()` on the grid and not on the whole page you need the relative offset of the row to the grid and not to the page. You get the relative offset to the parent with [`position()`](http://api.jquery.com/position/) ([`offset()`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/) gives you the offset relative to the document). And you don't need to substract the offset of the grid, actually you need to add the [`scrollTop()`](http://api.jquery.com/scrolltop/) value to get the proper value for `scrollTop` even if the grid was already scrolled.

This is how you it works:

```
var kendoGrid = grid.data("kendoGrid");
kendoGrid.element.find(".k-grid-content").animate({
                            scrollTop: kendoGrid.select().position().top 
                                       - kendoGrid.element.find('.k-grid-content').position().top 
                                       + kendoGrid.element.find('.k-grid-content').scrollTop()
                    });
```

You can try it here: http://dojo.telerik.com/OvIMa

Comment: If I select like this it throw's error on the change event, the offset().top property doesn't exist for this.select() and this.content.find('.k-grid-content')

Comment: @user3647642: Yes, you are right, my code only worked for the example I used, but that was coincidence. I updated my answer...

Comment: I found a new solution (row.height -1) * index where index is the index of the registration